# Shell scripting - Comparing floating number within if then else

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I need to make a comparison between floating numbers within the if.
For example,

```
if [1.1 -gt .45] && [1.1 -lt 2.9]

Then
...

fi
```

In the case of my program I've tried ...

```
if [ "$ {restogpsweek [0]} -gt 0.1"] && [ "$ {restogpsweek [0]} -lt 2.2"]

if [ "$ {restogpsweek [0]} -gt 0.1" | bc] && [ "$ {restogpsweek [0]} -lt 2.2" | bc]

if [`echo" $ {restogpsweek [0]} -gt 0.1 "| bc`] && [ `echo" $ {restogpsweek [0]} -lt 2.2 "| bc`]
```

and "n" other things and not found ...

Does anyone know how to do these comparisons?

Hugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` can not do floating point arithmetics.

You can use a more advanced shell like `zsh`:

```
% [[ 1.1 -gt .45 ]] && echo 'Ok'
Ok
```

Or use `bc` to do the comparison:

```
$ echo '1.1 > .45' | bc -l
1
```

`bc` returns 1 if true and 0 if false.

Comment: So, I only can use `bash` with floating point if it is a calculus..

to compare I need to change to the another shell like `zsh`, is it?
Thanks a lot..

Comment: @RodrigoMendesdaRocha In bash, you need to take help of `bc`

Comment: to do some calculus i use, but, comparing within it, `bc` doesn't work